# Is there anyway to run and deploy ubuntu packages on Azure functions Startup?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

In my Az Function app, I have some ubuntu packages like Azure CLI and Kubectl that I need to install on the AZ Host whenever it starts a new container. I have already tried Start-up Commands and also going into the Bash. The former doesnt work and the latter tells me permission is denied and resource is locked.  Is there any way to install these packages on function start-up in Azure Functions?

Comment: You should specifty the package that you need to install in requirements.txt. After deploy, Azure will install package based on this txt file. And at last, all of the packages in the txt will be integrated into a new package. So if you try to install after deploy, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to install the package via bash, it is impossible and will not be dealt with at all. The reason is because when you use python to write functions and deploy them to linux os on azure, in fact it installs various packages according to requirements.txt, and finally merges these packages into a whole. When you run the function on azure, you are based on this whole package. Therefore, if it is incorrect to try to install the package after deployment, you should specify the package to be installed in requirements.txt before deployment and then deploy to azure.